# select columns after named columns

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame of the following form in R

| First | a | b | c | Second | a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | 3 | 8 | 1 |  | 7 | 6 | 8 |
|  | 5 | 9 | 4 |  | 2 | 8 | 5 |

I'm trying to write something that selects the three columns following "First" & "Second", and puts them into new data frames titled "First" & "Second" respectively. I'm thinking of using the strategy below (where df is the dataframe I outline above), but am unsure how to make it such that R takes the columns that follow the ones I specify

```
names <- c("First", "Second")
for (i in c){
     i <- (something to specify the 3 columns following df$i)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An option is to `split.default` to split the `data.frame` into a `list` of `data.frame`s

```r
split.default(df, cumsum(names(df) %in% names))
#$`1`
#  First a b c
#1    NA 3 8 1
#2    NA 5 9 4
#
#$`2`
#  Second a b c
#1     NA 7 6 8
#2     NA 2 8 5
```

The expression `cumsum(...)` creates the indices according to which to group and split columns.

---

### Sample data

```r
df <- read.table(text = "First  a   b   c   Second  a   b   c
'' 3    8   1   ''  7   6   8
'' 5    9   4   ''  2   8   5", header = T, check.names = F)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get position of `names` vector in column names of the data and subset the next 3 columns from it.

```
names <- c("First", "Second")
inds <- which(names(df) %in% names)
result <- Map(function(x, y) df[x:y], inds + 1, inds + 3)
result

#[[1]]
#  a b c
#1 3 8 1
#2 5 9 4

#[[2]]
#  a b c
#1 7 6 8
#2 2 8 5
```

To create separate dataframes you can name the list and use `list2env`

```
names(result) <- names
list2env(result, .GlobalEnv)
```